# How can you get the FrameworkName of the current running environment?

Tags: c#, frameworks, runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Current .NET CLR version at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826688/get-current-net-clr-version-at-runtime)

The `System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName` class is a strongly typed indicator of a .NET Framework version. It differs based on version number, profile (Client Profile) etc. At runtime, how can you get the `FrameworkName` correct for the runtime environment in which the code is being executed? For example, a `FrameworkName` corresponding to net40 if you're running in a normal , non-Client Profile setup.

Note - the version of a specific assembly, the version of the compiler used, etc. are not a match here - you might have compiled an assembly with a 2.0 compiler but it may be running in a 4.5 runtime environment.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that - that doesn't tell you if you're running under Client Profile, etc.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the question regarding .NET CLR runtime version. The result of that is a version string, which does not tell you if you're running under a specific client profile, silverlight, etc. See the docs on the constructors for a `FrameworkName` instance for more details - a simple runtime version does not give you the data to construct a valid string (you have no Profile information). Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414023.aspx