# .NET Core current version

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, version

How can I determine in which version of .NET Core is my app running?

I tried to determine this from IHostingEnvironment (also Startup.cs and Program.cs) without success.

This question: [Get Current .NET CLR version at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826688/get-current-net-clr-version-at-runtime) is related to .NET Framework. My question is about .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the runtime version from `PlatformServices.Default.Application.RuntimeFramework` property under `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions`.

In `Program.cs`:

```
Console.WriteLine(PlatformServices.Default.Application.RuntimeFramework);
```

UPDATED:
According to this [aspnet/Announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/237), `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` has been removed, so `RuntimeFramework` is to be replaced with:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>().FrameworkName);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the quick ways is going to the menu bar and choose `Project->Properties->Application`

[image]

Then you'll see what's the target framework version your project is using.

Answer (score 0):

If `using System.Reflection;` is undesired, then `GetCustomAttributes` can be used.

```
static string GetFrameworkName()
            => ((System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute)
                    (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute), true)[0]))
                    .FrameworkName; // Example: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0
```