# How to know if I running under .NET Framework or .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly

Say I have a library, in Nuget, that compiled to `netstandard2.0` to support both `netcoreapp2.1` and `net471`.

Now, at compile-time, I don't know if I running under `net471`, `netcoreapp2.1`, **or `netstandard2.0`** (I emphasize this because I can't just compile my dll to both `netstandard` and `net471`, because if the **calling assembly** is `netstandard2.0`, I still don't know what about the **entry assembly**).

How can I know **at runtime** which TargetFramwork I running?

---

I know there is a solution like this:

```cs
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?
    .GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()?
    .FrameworkName
```

But if you run this in MSTest and `net471`, the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == null`, so I don't want to break tests in projects that uses my Nuget.

Comment: Have you tried Compiler directives

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51974946/451518

Comment: Are you shure that you need to reference to compiler? So, I see you not fully understand the differece of .net standart, .net core and .net framework. So, there are only 2 types of CLR: .net core and .net framework. So, .net standart is only specification, that gives you a confidence that environment are supported a API that you want to use. So, ALL api that specifies in .net standart are suports by .net framework and by .net core. It's created to avoid the code that depends on Framework version.

Comment: You can use either  Environment.Version (will return only the version) or RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription (will return version and framework name)

Comment: Hi, thanks!
Just testing the `FrameworkDescription` and back to here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` gives you a string:

The strings **start with**:

```
".NET" (for .NET 5 and later versions)
".NET Core" (for .NET Core 1.0 - 3.1)
".NET Framework"
".NET Native"`
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation.frameworkdescription?view=net-6.0

Comment: So if all of them *start* with `.NET`, how would you differentiate the newest core versions then?