# How to programmatically verify that .Net runtime is newer than a specific version

Tags: c#, .net, runtime

I know that with the following command I can get the runtime version

```
var runtimeVer = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription;
```

In my case it returns **".NET 6.0.7"**

What i need is to verify programmatically that the version is > 6.0.4.

I would prefer not doing that with a string compare. Is there any best practice or better alternative?

UPDATE: I do not just need a way to get the current version, but a safe way to make sure if it is newer than a specific version, while avoiding string comparison or regex complex expressions

Comment: `Environment.Version` maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Current .NET CLR version at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826688/get-current-net-clr-version-at-runtime)

Comment: Thank you, but not actually. I need to compare it with a specific version and see if the current is newer. ie. something like "6.0.7" > "6.0.4"

Comment: So what's wrong with `System.Environment.Version > new Version(6, 0, 4)`

Comment: That works! thank you, do you want to add it as an answer so I accept it?

Comment: You should have a link above to accept the suggested duplicate

Comment: But, that is not duplicate, it is just related, on the getting part. I needed the way to compare it. I already made a relevant update.

Comment: Seems a bit too simple to have a whole separate question "How to compare two `Version` objects?" answer "Use `>`"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246463/discussion-between-cnom-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the helpful comment of Charlieface I managed to do exactly what I was trying with the following code

```
  if (System.Environment.Version > new Version(6, 0, 4))
        {
          //do whatever needed, the runtime version supports it
        }
```